# Restrict return to execute in function

Tags: angular

Hi I am working on Angular application.

```
function onMap(asset) {
    if (!service.realstate()) {      
        NotifierService.info('test');
        return;
    }
}
```

Here i m checking state of active environment if it is not real then i am simply notifing user and returning from this function.
But some time return got executing before Notifier Service executed.
Here Notifier Service internally uses a angular toaster service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are calling `onMap` function out of angular realm. If it is called out of angular realm then  you need to call `$scope.$apply` or put it in `$timeout`. You can read more [here](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster/issues/184).

```
function onMap(asset) {
    if (!service.realstate()) {      
        $timeout(() =>NotifierService.info('test'), 0);
        // $scope.$apply() // <- you can use this also instead of timeout.
        return;
    }
}
```